# ffmpeg command is not run when I hit using exec function in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I have to convert some video to "h264" using FFmpeg.When I hit the below command as a cloud user with ssh login it converts successful.

```
 ffmpeg -i /var/www/media/photos/video_demo/55291482115655.MP4 -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=-1:300 -threads 0 -pass 1 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 500k -f mp4 /var/www/media/photos/video_demo/5888.MP4.
```

But when I run this command using PHP it gives me an error.

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i /var/www/media/photos/video_demo/55291482115655.MP4 -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=-1:300 -threads 0 -pass 1 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 500k -f mp4 /var/www/media/photos/video_demo/85493.MP4 ";
  exec($cmd .' 2>&1', $outputAndErrors, $return_value);



  php error: Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I also followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121035/ffmpeg-working-in-command-line-but-not-in-php-using-exec?rq=1) similar to my problem but still not get solution for this problem,In my server there is 3 FFmpeg installed.

Comment: Might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877031/error-while-opening-encoder-for-output-stream-0-0-maybe-incorrect-parameters